# Get request history using http package

Tags: dart

When I make an http request to `http://google.com`, the request is first redirected to `http://google.com/` and then to `http://www.google.com/`. When using the `http` Pub package, is there a way for me know the history of a request and get a list of all the redirects?  If the `http` package does not support this, is there some other way to get a request's history in Dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `http` package does not provide information on the number of redirects leading to a response. One reason for that is that it is the long term plan to make `http` available in the browser. In the browser it would wrap `HttpRequest` from `dart:html` which does not have the redirection history.

However `dart:io` does provide information on the redirects in the `HttpClientResponse` object. The following code prints the number of redirects.

```
import "dart:io" as io;

main() {
  var client = new io.HttpClient();
  client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"))
      .then((request) => request.close())
      .then((response) => print(response.redirects.length));
}
```

See [HttpClientResponse.redirects](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_io/HttpClientResponse.html#redirects) for more information.